# Recover Session in Session_End method

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I need recover the `Session` of my user when he leaves the application, so I treat this in my `Session_End` method, in `Global.asax`

```
    protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lock (objeto2)
        {
            try
            {                       
                Thread tSan1 = new Thread(() => alteraStatusUsuario(Session["loginid"].ToString(), Session["agenciaid"].ToString()));
                tSan1.Start();
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

But when I call `Session["loginid"]` or `Session["agenciaid"]` occurs an `HttpException`, that was unhandled.

But the curious thing, if I put a breakpoint in this method, it works fine, and both `Session` recovers the correct value.

Can someone help me ?

Comment: I think `Session` calls into `HttpContext.Current` which is keyed by thread.  So, I doubt you can access the session in another thread.

Comment: If @MikeChristensen is correct (which is probably the case); read the session values outside the thread delegate into string variables, and the string values will be available when the thread executes.